# Passing variable from background to popup on Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, variables, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a simple extension, which is passing a variable from background to popup. The problem is, I get 'undefined' response.

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Get var",
  "description": "get var",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Get that variable",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
 var myURL = 'aaa';
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    var myURL = bg.myURL;
  alert(myURL)

});
```

Comment: Try `window.myURL = 'aaa';` in background.js

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally I found the problem, I read background pages need background permission to work ([chrome extension permissions documentation here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html)). So I changed manifest like this:

```
{
  "name": "Get var",
  "description": "get var",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab,background"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Get that variable",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: Background-pages certainly do **not** need the `background` permission to work. The `background` permission is for a very different purpose, as clearly stated in the documentation you link to: _When any installed hosted app, packaged app, or extension has "background" permission, Chrome runs (invisibly) as soon as the user logs into their computer—before the user launches Chrome. The "background" permission also makes Chrome continue running (even after its last window is closed) until the user explicitly quits Chrome._

Comment: BTW, if this is what you wanted (running in the background), you should have mentioned it in your question to save yourself (and ourselves) some time ;)

Comment: I changed nothing but added a background permission and it worked. What I wanted was to make it work somehow :)

Comment: I can asure you that the reason it was not working was not the missing 'background` permission **unless** you wanted that _Chrome runs (invisibly) as soon as the user logs into their computer—before the user launches Chrome_. If this is the case you should have mentioned it in your question. If not then there is some other issue with your code which might accidentally have been "fixed" when adding the `background` permission (e.g. a timing issue of some sort), but it would be better to track it down and properly solve it as it is likely to come up again later.

Comment: I shared all files I have here. There is no other mysterious code, I can asure you :)

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, I copied and pasted the posted code into my extension and it worked fine. So, it is something else. (But, to end this, if you are happy with it and it works for you, it fine by me. Only, please, don't give false information that in order to access a variable in the background page you need the `background` permission.)

Answer (score 10):

Your code (exactly as you posted it in your question) is correct and should work fine. (In fact when I created a sample extension using the code you provided, it did work as expected.)
You either accidentaly changed something when copying-pasting the actual code or there is something else messing things up (something you left out of your post).

---

BTW, I would suggest looking into **[event-pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)** (i.e. non-persistent background-pages) which are more resource-friendly. Keep in mind, that moving to an event-page would require some changes in order for the code to work:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function (bg) {
        var myUrl = bg.myUrl;
        alert(myUrl);
    });
});
```

<sub>**Note**: I do not in any way imply that the reason you receive `undefined` is that you use a persistent background-page. The code you posted should work fine with a persistent background-page - it is just better practice to use an event page (whenever possible).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar issue; my problem was that I didn't reload the extension after changing the manifest.

I would guess that the OP's issue was the same.